# How to make permission for groups and administrators

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am currently building a API but i am unable to determine the easiest way to allow certain methods for group members and full permission for eg. administrators (or even another group).

Basically i want to allow group members to access all methods except `POST`, while administrators (or another group) have full access.

**Pseudo:**

```
def get(self, request):
     if (user.is_superuser | Group.objects.get(name='APIUsers').user_set.filter(id=user.id).exists()):
     # Do something usefull
```

Is something in this fashion possible, while still obeying the Django-REST-Framework API?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for Django REST Framework's [Custom Permissions](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions#custom-permissions). You could also take a look at `IsAdminUser` `IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly` for inspiration.

For example you could use:

```
from rest_framework import permissions

class IsAdminOrReadOnly(permissions.BasePermission):
    """Allow unsafe methods for admin users only."""

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if not request.user or not request.user.is_authenticated():
            return False
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return True
        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return bool(Group.objects.get(name='Patient').
                        user_set.filter(id=request.user.id).exists())
        return False
```

You can also take a look ad [DjangoModelPermissions](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/permissions.py#L80).

Then it's just a matter of using the new permission either on the whole API:

```
# in settings.py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'myapp.permissions.IsAdminOrReadOnly',
    )
}
```

or on each view as needed.

Comment: Is that code complete? I understand the API in a way that the method `has_permission` or `has_object_permission` has to be implemented in a permission.

Comment: I tried to implement this example, but for some reason i can still `GET` without being logged in and as admin im unable to `POST`.

Comment: For point 1) replace `return True` with `return request.user and request.user.is_authenticated`. For point 2), it depends on your implementation, but `request.user.has_perm` sould always be True for a superuser.

Comment: I've update the example implementation, it should come closer to your needs.

Comment: There was a minor correction. Only thing that bothers me is actually the `allow` data in the API interface. It claims `POST` is possible for a `APIUser` which is not the case.

Comment: After 2hours attempts i cant figure out how the `Allow` can be modified.

Comment: @JavaCake: you can override the `allowed_method` property on your `APIView` classes, see the [code here](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/views.py#L107). Technically `POST` is allowed, provided you have the right credentials. I'm not sure the `Allow` header is supposed to change on a given URL, but that's an interesting question.

Comment: I have seen the `Allow` header change before along with the permissions, but i am actually not sure why this does not come natural with `Permissions`. It seems a little misleading from the API's perspective.

Answer (score 1):

For users in group called api_users you have:

```
class IsApiUser(BasePermission):
    #Allows access only to api_users group members.
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if request.user and request.user.groups.filter(name='api_users'):
            return True
        return False
```

next

```
class custListView(RetrieveAPIView):
    permission_classes = (IsApiUser,)
    serializer_class = custSerializer
    ...
```

hope it will help uyou